# Can't download excel file from api - xlsx/csv

Tags: javascript, nestjs, exceljs

I return workbook as arraybuffer from api then trying to download on react side with blob.

It downloads file but csv file has bunch of numbers not the proper data.

**Current Output**

> { type: 'Buffer', data: [67,40,3,10....] }

**-from api**

```
  ....
 return await workbook.csv.writeBuffer()
```

**-react side**

```
const handleDownload = async() => {
    const response= await userHelper.getExcel()

    saveAs(new Blob([response?.data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' }), 'deneme.csv');
  }
```

Comment: Have you added the needed headers?

Comment: Could you remind

Comment: Add `'Content-Type', 'text/csv'` to the header. Maybe it helps.

Comment: You can modify the question title also, if you want to download CSV, not XLS/XLSX file. That way it can be easy for others to find this.

Comment: it still downloads xlsx / csv file but content are just numbers ...

Comment: And using `.toString()` what's the result?

Comment: I tried convert to base64 on server. Now it returns random chars not the proper data :)

Answer (score 0):

Your response like ArrayBuffer, so please add `responseType` to config:

```
axios.get(
    "http://localhost:5000/folder.zip", //hosted with server
    { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }))
.then(res => {
      const file = new Blob([res], { type: 'text/csv' }
      let url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      let a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = url;
      a.download = 'deneme.csv';
      a.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
});
```

Hope that it helps